# TabBar application slow

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem, I have a TabBar application with 3 tabs, at the start of app if I try to change tab (only on specific tab) the changing is a bit slow, after the first time all is fast, how can I check the time of specific process (method) for find the problem?